# Python code snippet in two blockquotes of markdown

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-lab

I am trying to write two code snippets in a blockquote of Markdown (JupyterLab, if that makes any difference). Here is a minimal example:

````
>  ```python
test = [12, 15, 20]
test
```
yields

> ```python
[12, 15, 20]
```
````

When I run it, I am not getting two blockquotes. Here is the output I am getting:

[image: Output]

What is my mistake here?

Comment: can you post the exact output that you're getting please?

Comment: @rafadeboas sure thing. Just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the whole blockquote with `>` characters:

````
>  ```python
> test = [12, 15, 20]
> test
> ```

yields

> ```python
> [12, 15, 20]
> ```
````

Yes, this is slightly harder to type, but it renders properly:

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter Lab's rendering]

This also aligns with [one of Markdown's original design goals](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/):

> The idea is that a Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it's been marked up with tags or formatting instructions.

Prefixing the whole blockquote makes it look like a blockquote even in its source form.

Note that I have also added a blank line before "yields", as this also helps readability of the source. It also removes "yields" from the blockquote. If "yields" is supposed to be in the blockquote you can simply add more `>` characters:

````
>  ```python
> test = [12, 15, 20]
> test
> ```
>
> yields
````

Answer (score 1):

I had to go and try this out myself...

You hav to explicitly tell Jupyter that you want a Markdown cell:

[image: Jupyterlab Markdown]

After telling Jupyter that you are in a Markdown cell, you can achieve what you want easily:

[image: Jupyter Markdown cell before run]

[image: Jupyter Markdown cell after run]

Edit: I'd misunderstood your question. With blockquotes:

[image: Jupyter code in blockquote]

````
> ```python
> test = [12, 15, 20]
> test
> ```

yields

> ```python
> [12, 15, 20]
> ```
````

Also take a look at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314123/9918829) for more information.

Comment: You are creating one Blockquote. Try two instead. That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.